# Why does JAXB sometimes map to JAXBElement?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

There is a placeholder answer over at [the unofficial guide](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/guide/Mapping_of__xs_element____to_JAXBElement.html) with a link to an article which (to me) seems quite unrelated.

I use XJC to generate my JAXB classes and while most of them map to each other as expected, some elements get mapped to `JAXBElement<Foo>`. This is most annoying for graphs with cycles, where sometimes the parent node of a Foo element will be the `JAXBElement<Foo>`, which doesn't itself have a parent property, breaking the cycle.

I can think of various workarounds, but it would be much nicer if someone could explain this behaviour to me. Why does JAXB sometimes map a `<Foo>` element to `JAXBElement<Foo>` instead of Foo?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639313/xsd-formatting-elementcomplextype-vs-complextype-element/3639375#3639375 for an explanation

Comment: @skaffman: Eh? I don't see how your answer relates to whether xjc chooses `JAXBElement<Foo>` over `Foo`.

Comment: @Chris: Because it is determined in part by the choice of anonymous types or names types in the source schema.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JAXBElement is used to preserve the element name/namespace in use cases where enough information is not present in the object model.  The most common occurence is with substitution groups:

**With Substitution Group:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.org" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="anElement"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="anElement" type="xs:string"/>

    <xs:element name="aSubstituteElement" type="xs:string" substitutionGroup="anElement"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Will generate:

```
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "anElement"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "anElement", namespace = "http://www.example.org", type = JAXBElement.class)
    protected JAXBElement<String> anElement;

    public JAXBElement<String> getAnElement() {
        return anElement;
    }

    public void setAnElement(JAXBElement<String> value) {
        this.anElement = ((JAXBElement<String> ) value);
    }

}
```

**Without Substitution Group:**

If you remove the substitution group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.org" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="anElement"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="anElement" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:schema>
```

The following class will be generated:

```
package org.example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "anElement"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String anElement;

    public String getAnElement() {
        return anElement;
    }

    public void setAnElement(String value) {
        this.anElement = value;
    }

}
```

You may also get a JAXBElement when you unmarshal, compare the following examples:

- [Without any JAXB metada the result will be wrapped in a JAXBElement](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics)
- [Using @XmlRootElement eliminates the root level JAXBElement](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/JAXBCustomizations)

Comment: Thanks, substitution groups are indeed where this is happening. So is it then a bug that in `afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent)` these substitutable classes are being passed their own JAXBElement as their `parent`? Especially since there doesn't seem to be a way to get the real parent element from the JAXBElement.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Metro JAXB (the reference implementation, included in Java SE 6).  In the MOXy JAXB implementation (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) the correct parent object is passed to the afterUnmarshal method.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid mapping to JAXBElement?
I have done this things it work for me :

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
           jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
           jaxb:version="2.0">

    <xs:annotation>
       <xs:appinfo>
          <jaxb:globalBindings generateValueClass="false">
           <xjc:simple />
          </jaxb:globalBindings>
       </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>

</xs:schema>
```

Save this file in the xml file and supply as binding files.

Reference [Link](https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple)

Generate JAXB classes using eclipse dont forget to give binding files created with above xml and check "Allow Vendor extensions" as below:

[image]

With changes i am able Get rid of JAXBElement in classes generated xjc for convert xsd to JAXB generated classes.