# JAXBElement in WebService data structure

Tags: java, jaxb

I am learning JAX-WS and i also was introduced with JAXB. I can use it to (un)marshal java(xml) to xml(java). But what is the purpose of this line then i generated my WS data with Apache CXF:

```
@XmlElementRef(name = "Id", namespace = "External.Test", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> id;
```

1. Why it can't be just `String id` instead of `JAXBElement<String> id`
   ?
2. How can I convert request data (let's say java POJO) into
       structure like this above? (I am talking about mapping from POJO to
       this exposed WS structure with fields wrapped into JAXBElements)

Comment: It can't just be a string because you are dealing with a web service. Web services are used via different languages, and some languages handle strings differently. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489306/parameter-jaxbelement-string

Comment: @j.con This has nothing to do with string handling in different languages.

Comment: @lexicore oh yea? Try to consume an `int` from a java web service in C# when the `int` is null. C# does not allow `int` to be null, only a `int?` that is why a standard wrapper is used...

Comment: @j.con I repeat, `@XmlElementRef` or `JAXBElement<String>` vs. `String` has nothing to do with string handling in different languages. This depends on how the originating schema is defined. The problem you're addressing is the nillability. Well, yes, `nillable="true"` is ONE of the reasons for `@XmlElementRef`, but it is not the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- This structure is used depending on how did you define your schema. For instance, if you use a sustitution group. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659338/3046834) for more info.

2.- Here some code that might help you:
Let´s say that you POJO defines a structure like this:

```
public JAXBElement<?> getObjectData() {
    return objectData;
}
```

Then, when you unmarshalled the request that you have received, is filled with a String that you want to recover:

```
JAXBElement<String> rncElem = (JAXBElement<String>) dataContainer.getObjectData();
return rncElem.getValue();
```